# Javascript - confirm() inside a jquery .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, confirm

I have the following

```
$("element").click(function() {
  var foo=bar;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
   confirm('Dialogue');
  }
});
```

But I would like to bool the confirm function. I've already tried

```
$("element").click(function() {
  var foo=bar;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
    var confirm=confirm('Dialogue');
    if (confirm==true) {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
  }
});
```

But no confirmation box is generated. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `(confirm=true)` should be `(confirm==true)` or `(confirm)`  also what is bar in this context `var foo=bar`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a few issues. First issue is you are defining a variable with the name `confirm`. Not good! Rename it to `isGood` or something else.

The other bug is right here:

```
if (confirm=true) {
```

`confirm=true` is assignment, not a comparison.

It needs to be

```
if (confirm==true) {
```

or just

```
if (confirm) {
```

So your code would be something like

```
var bar = "bar";
$("button").click(function() {
  var foo=bar;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
    var isGood=confirm('Dialogue');
    if (isGood) {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: stupid me and my noobie typing errors. It was because i had confirm=true instead of confirm==true. =/

Answer (score 15):

```
if( !confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?')) {
                    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

When you declare a variable anywhere in your function, it automatically gets "pulled" to the top as a local variable.  When you call confirm as a function, it finds the local variable first (which hasn't been defined yet) and doesn't go up the scope chain to `window` where the function lives.

```
$("element").click(function() {
  var foo=bar;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
    var confirm=confirm('Dialogue');
    if (confirm==true) {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
  }
});
```

is the same as

```
$("element").click(function() {
  var foo=bar, confirm = undefined;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
  confirm=confirm('Dialogue');
  ...
});
```

You could 1) rename your variable, 2) call `window.confirm("Dialog")` telling it you want the global function instead of the local variable or 3) just put the confirm call inside an if

```
$("element").click(function() {
  var foo=bar;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
    if (confirm('Dialogue')) {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

All of the comments about the comparison are correct, however, the reason the confirm dialog is not showing is that you are wiping out the confirm box object.

Change the name of the `confirm` var.

```
$(element).click(function() {
  var confirm1 = confirm('Dialogue');
  if (confirm1) {
    alert('true');
  } else {
    alert('false');
  }  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjGZj/

Compare that to this one which doesn't work.

```
$(element).click(function() {
  var confirm = confirm('Dialogue');
  if (confirm) {
    alert('true');
  } else {
    alert('false');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjGZj/1/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (confirm) {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.confirm` class to an element then in jQuery write..

```
$('.confirm').click(function() {

    return confirm("Are you sure?");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

sharing my working example as very simple.

```
        $("#delete-category-btn").click(function(){

        var id = $(this).data('categoryid');
        console.log(id);

        if (confirm('are you sure want to delete?')) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url:"{{url('admin/delete-categories')}}/"+id,
                success: function(result) {
                    location.reload();
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial though is your main problem lies here

```
var foo=bar;
  if ( foo == "bar" ) {
```

what is bar?  I believe you intended to make the following assignment `var foo="bar";` which would make the if statement evaluate as true and execute your confirmation dialog.

In addition the following is inaccurate

```
var confirm = confirm("dialog");
if (confirm=true)
```

just use this:

```
if (confirm("dialog"))
```

Comment: heh? when performing a var == string, string is always surrounded by quotes (either single or double depending on usage) or else it gets evaluated as a variable instead of a string. So no, it wouldn't be written as foo="bar". But your 2nd part is true. -1 +1